# Set X and Y offset to puppeteer page

Tags: puppeteer

I am setting page width and height using `page.setViewport()` and using the chromium in kiosk mode in puppeteer, I know passing  `--window-position` and `--window-size` as args does not work in kiosk mode, is there any way I can set X and Y positions for the page (not kiosk window) inside the kiosk mode application?